# Possible to re-use flex forms?

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications, flash-builder

Is it possible to use a form for both initial creation and updation based on a target url? For example, if a user goes to `http://localhost/create/new` can I have a flex form with empty input fields be shown, but if a user goes to `http://localhost/update/1` can I have the same flex form, but with input fields filled in be shown instead?

Also, I have 3 forms that take the SAME data and have essentially the same format; can I have a `parent` form from which I can derive the 3 forms, rather than having 3 separate applications for each form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to code it.  Either by having separate SWFs at the URLs you specified that do different things based on the URL variable handed in (not recommended) or by using something like the BrowserManager to control the URL display.

And yes you can create a parent form and derive different child forms from this.  In MXML you'll just create a component based off the 'parent'.  In AS3 you'll create a component that extends the parent.

I'd question your path, though.  When developing Applications, I recommend you try to get out of the HTML page / linking model.  As one example, when was the last time someone asked you for a link to the excel formula editor [for example]?

Comment: Could you expound on your recommendation? I don't fully understand what you're getting at. Currently, my web app uses html/js for forms, and to add features/functionality I'm planning on using flex based forms. The user is not required to provide URLs directly, but rather can simply click on provided links/buttons. I don't intent to use flex solely, but rather use it in conjunction with html/js where it makes sense.

Comment: Do you just want to use Flex for your forms? If so, IMHO Adobe Flex isn't the right way, because your forms will have a lot of "overhang" and you should keep going with js and html.

Comment: I want to use flex for forms and table/chart displays. Further, the forms aren't basic input text boxes/areas, but rather include image/file uploads and image ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Use BrowserManager to sniff the inbound URL, and use states to modify the form fields.